# Is it possible to get route data on runtime outside of controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wonder if it's possible to somehow get the route value outside of controller?

This is what I've tried. I also tried to do `.Values["{projectId}"];` but I still get `null`.

```
[RoutePrefix("projects")]
public class UsergroupController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{projectId}/usergroups"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // Url: /projects/123/usergroups
        // Response: null
        var projectId = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["projectId"];
        return Ok(projectId);
    }
}
```

I found that it is located, but in a very strange matter. Maybe there might be some kind of LINQ query to get it?

**RouteData-Values-Values-0-0-Values-0**

[image]

Comment: I think ASP.Net MVC and WebAPI do not share all route information... Should be relatively easy to see the problem by inspecting `RouteData.Values` in debugger.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good point, I found that it in fact is located somewhere, but the question is - how do I get there?

Comment: Based on picture you need to check what is the value of outer `Keys` (surprising for me too... also I'm more surprised that you are able to see values at all - I expected WebAPI to have separate routing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WebApi has it's own nested RouteData, this is because it doesn't use the `RouteData` class in `System.Web` but it's own `HttpRouteData` class.

The WebApi routing adds an entry under the key `MS_SubRoutes`, which WebApi uses for it's internal routes.

I've written an extension method which flattens the WebApi route data into a `string/object` dictionary, which is what you might see in `RouteData.Values`

**WebApiExtensions.cs**

```
public static class WebApiExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> GetWebApiRouteData(this RouteData routeData)
    {
        if (!routeData.Values.ContainsKey("MS_SubRoutes"))
            return new Dictionary<string,object>();

        return ((IHttpRouteData[])routeData.Values["MS_SubRoutes"]).SelectMany(x => x.Values).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
[RoutePrefix("projects")]
public class UsergroupController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{projectId}/usergroups"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // Url: /projects/123/usergroups
        // Response: null
        object value = null;

        var webApiRouteData = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetWebApiRouteData();
        value = webApiRouteData["projectId"];

        return Ok(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me!, However, for some reason I was getting two different `HttpRouteData` elements with a repeated route. So when flattened with `SelectMany()` it it would fail at the `ToDictionary()` call since there were repeated keys. A `Distinct()` would fix that quickly, although it might not be elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Note the key used in this fix is incorrect, "currently" in .net 4.5 the key is **MS_DirectRouteMatches**.

routeData.Values["MS_SubRoutes"] should be routeData.Values["MS_DirectRouteMatches"]).